# Python CSV files: Printing all a user's details

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a piece of code wherein my user does a quiz and all that information is stored in a CSV file. I then, in another program, have the user input a username and, if it matches, it will print the scores etc for that user. However, I had the same user do the quiz again and, instead of printing all the quizzes and scores that user did, it just prints the latest one.

To show:
My CSV file looks like this

Ser15 A Sci-Med

Ser15 C Sci-Med

These are the rows. I want my program to print all the quizzes and grades 'Ser15' had, but it just prints the lastest.
How do I make my program print all of them? Here is my code below...

```
     def Report1():
        found=False
        UserFind=input("Please enter a username")
        with open("Report.csv","r") as c:
            for row in c:
                details=row.split(",")
                if UserFind in details[0]:
                    found=True
                else:
                  pass
            if found==True:
                print(details[0])
                print(details[1])
                print(details[2])
                print("These are your user's details!")
            else:
                print("User doesn't exist or wrong details...")
```

This is my result:

```
Please enter a choice: 3
Please enter a usernameSer15
Ser15
C
Sci-Med

These are your user's details!
```

As you can see it prints their latest information, not all of them...

This is part of my project so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: One thing right off the bat, you never need to do `if found==True:`. `if found:` will evaluate to the same expression and make your code look cleaner.

Comment: When you write to the CSV are you appending or writing... if you write it will overwright any information there before...

Comment: use the `csv` module to read csv files.

Comment: you should `break` your loop or you'll always get the last row.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is simply that

```
        for row in c:
            details=row.split(",")
            if UserFind in details[0]:
                found=True
```

doesn't stop the loop, so you'll get whatever is in the last row.

Just add `break` after `found=True` to stop at the matching row

Note that this linear search is not optimal if you want to perform several searches. Better build a dictionary out of csv rows:

```
import csv
with open("Report.csv","r") as c:
    cr=csv.reader(c)
    database = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in c}
```

now query `database` with `name in database` or/and `database.get(name)` to get the rest of the info.

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping through the CSV file, you should check if it is found and print it within the loop.

```
with open("Report.csv","r") as c:
    for row in c:
        details=row.split(",")
        if UserFind in details[0]:
            found=True
            print(details[0])
            print(details[1])
            print(details[2])
            print("These are your user's details!")
    if not found:
        print("User doesn't exist or wrong details...")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statements aren't inside the for-loop, but after it. So they only get run once. And your checking `found` to decide whether to print doesn't make sense: this prints based on whether any row matches, not whether the current one does. Also, there's no need to do `else: pass`. You should change your code to the following:

```
def Report1():
    found=False
    UserFind=input("Please enter a username")
    with open("Report.csv","r") as c:
        for row in c:
            details=row.split(",")
            if UserFind in details[0]:
                print(details[0])
                print(details[1])
                print(details[2])
                print("These are your user's details!")
                found= True
        if not found:
            print("User doesn't exist or wrong details...")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Report1():
    found=False
    UserFind=input("Please enter a username")
    with open("Report.csv","r") as c:
        for row in c:
            details=row.split(",")
            if UserFind in details[0]:
                print(details[0])
                print(details[1])
                print(details[2])
                print("These are your user's details!")
                found= True
        if not found:
            print("User doesn't exist or wrong details...")
```

Thank you to Accumulation!